# Fragment onCreateOptionsMenu not getting called on orientation change

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I have a activity having multiple fragments in viewpager. When I open option menu it adds menu items from particular fragment to option menu. I am using `android 4.2` and has `android:configChanges="orientation"` I have not added `screensize` due to which activity will be created on orientation change which I want.

When I open option menu all menus including fragment menu items are shown. But if I rotate device while option menus is showing only option menu items of activity are shown. I checked it is because fragment `onCreateOptionsMenu` is not called when I change orientation. How can I add fragment option menu items to already shown option menu while changing orientation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done by calling `setMenuVisibility(true);` in `onResume` of my Fragment class.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: With Android O,  `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu` is deprecated. Use directly `invalidateOptionsMenu()`

That's correct. `Android` will fire `onConfigurationChanged`

override it and call `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using Activity and supportInvalidateOptionsMenu is there in FragmentActivity. I called invalidateOptionsMenu in onConfigurationChanged and onResume of activity and fragment. But it is not addiing fragment menu item to already open option menu on orientation change.

Comment: `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` is deprecated now https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with a call to:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

In the onCreateView method of the Fragment